# How to export database and import it locally by C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

How to "clone" a database from a remote server to LocalDB database by a C# application? No relationships back to the remote database are needed.

**Background**

Application is written in C# using .NET 4.5.2 and supports two modes - online which connects to a remote MS SQL Server database, and offline which connects to a `LocalDB` database. The application primarily targets newer versions of the servers (if it matters, supporting only version 2014 is ok).

Before the user goes offline it should ask the application to clone the remote database to the `LocalDB` database (the local database is completely overwritten). The local database should be independent on the remote database, i.e. no slave nor replication.

Both the online and offline connection string contains name of the respective database. The application itself has no direct knowledge of the database name nor of the table names as this is managed by the connection strings and by the Entity Framework.

**Question**

How to "clone" the remote database to a `LocalDB` database (the remote database name and the `LocalDB` database name might be different)?

I prefer a solution which does not require to launch an external program, but this is not a hard requirement.

**Issues**

Copying through Entity Framework no tracking entities is unacceptable slow.

I am aware of the `BACKUP DATABASE` and `RESTORE DATABASE` commands, but I have found the following difficulties:

1. They require me to specify the name of the database. Is there a way how to default them to the initial database specified as part of the connection string?
2. The `RESTORE DATABASE` command contains names and paths of the respective data files on the disc (`MOVE` parts). Is there a way how to process it with specifying just the database name without providing the data files path? Or how to get the data files paths via SQL commands (to get the file names, I will just create a blank database, got the file names, optionally drop the database and use the retrieved file names)?

Is there a better way doing this?

Comment: I would suggest SqlBulkCopy class. It's in your tags, but you don't mention it in the text at all. Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know its actually a class. Thanks to your suggestion, I have found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy and used the provided `PerformBulkCopy` sample code to build the actual code.

Comment: I suggest to use SSIS packages to get latest data. You can do incremental or full refresh using that.

Comment: I apologize for not stating it before. The user can do (very limited) set of changes while running offline. The changes are then simulated by the app on the online data while switching to online. So I prefer complete rewrite of the offline database just to be safe. SSIS is not included in Express edition so it might make our life harder (there will be very light traffic made by the app on the database server so Express edition is ok if there is nothing better already deployed).

Comment: Truncate table + old school insert into in the local database would work. Or SqlBulkCopy for that matter. How many records in your largest table?

Comment: Not know yet, but at least 40 000. The `SqlBulCopy` way seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use a stored procedure i created, but first you need to create a linked server:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.servers WHERE name = 'SERVER')
            BEGIN-- 
                EXEC sp_dropserver 'SERVER', 'droplogins'
            END

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [SERVER]  create  LinkedServer ******/
            EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
            @server = N'SERVER', 
            @srvproduct=N'SQLNCLI', 
            @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
            @datasrc=N'192.168.1.1' -- IP address of a server   

             /* Add login data*/
            EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
            @useself='FALSE',
            @rmtsrvname='SERVER',
            @rmtuser='User',
            @rmtpassword='Pass'
```

Then you can create stored procedure on local server or execute the query directly from application, also for safety I am using a transaction in this example:

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[backupdatabase] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[backupdatabase]  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION           
            TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table_1]
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_1]
            SELECT * FROM [SERVER].[DB].[dbo].[table_1] 


            TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table_2]
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_2]
            SELECT * FROM [SERVER].[DB].[dbo].[table_2] 


            TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[table_3]
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_3]
            SELECT * FROM [SERVER].[DB].[dbo].[table_3]             
        COMMIT      
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
            SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
            RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
        END         
    END CATCH
END
```